# Convert rows to columns in SSIS. Unpivot?

Tags: ssis

If I have data like this

```
"","",WAREHOUSE ID,1,2,3,4,5...
"","",WAREHOUSE CODE,BOS,HOU,LAX,NYC,CHI...
"","",WAREHOUSE NAME,BOSTON,HOUSTON,LOS ANGELES,NEW YORK CITY,CHICAGO...
```

But want to transform it like this

```
 WAREHOUSE ID, WAREHOUSE CODE, WAREHOUSE NAME
 1,BOS,BOSTON
 2,HOU,HOUSTON
 3,LAX,LOS ANGELES
 ...
```

If, as above, [Column 2] is the column that contains what should be the header row, and Columns 3 through 40 contain what should be row values, which columns get selected and set to pass through for the UNPIVOT to perform the desired transposition?

Or is UNPIVOT not even what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Unpivot Transformation should work, as long as the number of input columns does not vary.

Looking at your example, it looks like [Column 2] (e.g. WAREHOUSE ID) should be set as the Pivot Key Value.  You can ignore any output columns that you dont want to output e.g. the Pivot Key Value Column Name.

Comment: You should attempt to provide a solution showing that `UNPIVOT` works.

Comment: @Mike Honey: Unpivot does seem to be the most likely candidate, but I have not been able to find the right settings to achieve the result, could you elaborate?

Comment: Elaborated my answer - see above.